# Custom frontend page for plugin without a 'physical' page?

Tags: plugin-development, rewrite-rules

I need to create a frontend page (and sub-pages) which will display custom data that is saved in the database but is not part of wordpress, it is not a post or page as such but API called data. I do not want to use a short code because of the need of sub-pages.

I have looked at the following but don't seem to be able to make it work as required: [Dynamic URL, not a physical page within the database](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/212856/dynamic-url-not-a-physical-page-within-the-database)

What I need is to have for example `site.com/mypage/` but I do not want 'mypage' to exist in the backend.

I have achieved this with:

```
public function mypage_rewrite_ext() {
    global $wp_rewrite;
    $plugin_url = plugins_url( 'mypage.php', __FILE__ );
    $plugin_url = substr( $plugin_url, strlen( home_url() ) + 1 );
    // The pattern is prefixed with '^'
    // The substitution is prefixed with the "home root", at least a '/'
    // This is equivalent to appending it to `non_wp_rules`
    $wp_rewrite->add_external_rule( 'mypage$', $plugin_url );
}
```

But I need my page to still be within WordPress as I need to use the header and footer.

I have tried the following from the above linked question, but this just redirects to the home page (even after re-saving permalinks):

```
public function add_query_vars( $query_vars )
{
    $query_vars[] = 'test';
    return $query_vars;
}

public function add_endpoint()
{
    add_rewrite_rule('^mypage/?', 'index.php?__test=1', 'top');
    flush_rewrite_rules(false); //// <---------- REMOVE THIS WHEN DONE
}

public function sniff_requests($wp_query)
{
    global $wp;

    if(isset($wp->query_vars[ '__test' ])) {
        add_filter('template_include', function ($original_template) {

            // change the default template to a google map template
            return plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'mypage.php';
        });
    }
}
```

Any ideas on 1) what I am doing wrong and/or 2) how I can achieve this?

This is the result from the analyser:
[image]

Comment: Just curious, why are you averse to having actual WP 'pages' for these? You could assign them each a custom Page template that pulls in your non-WP data (as well as WP header/footer) and note in the content editor that the page content is controlled in the theme, not in content editor.

Comment: Because it's going to be a custom hierarchy for 1000's of items, so I don't want to have to make a page per one, or use a shortcode as I will need to eventually have /mypage/myotherpage/mylastpage/

Comment: Have you tested with monkeyman rewrite rules analyser plugin to verify that the URL you expected actually matches the rewrite rule? Note that you added `test` as a query variable, but you used instead `__test` which isn't the same

Comment: @TomJNowell I have it there but to be honest I'm not sure what to expect from it. See attached image (Just updating with the correct var as well, didn't notice that - which now make 'mypage' go to the archive page)

Comment: You should be seeing your rewrite rule, either `index.php?__test=1` or `^mypage/?`, it would appear you aren't. WordPress never tries to load the template because it never matches your rewrite rule to the URL

Comment: If the page doesn't exist, what do expect template tags in theme header and footer would output? I would choose one physical root page to base your rules on, otherwise you will need to manually populate a main query object.

Comment: See updated image.

Comment: Fixed it - was another typo. I'll delete the question when I can :)

Comment: So you add `test` as a query variable, but then you use `__test`, and finally you look for `__properties`

Comment: @TomJNowell yeah, last thing on pre holiday weekend fails - I will remove the question when able to :)

Comment: @Aravona Don't delete the question, answer it! Who knows who else might have the same issue but not spot the problem as you did

Answer (score 3):

**"What I need is to have for example site.com/mypage/ but I do not want 'mypage' to exist in the backend."**

It's a bit late, but maybe someone else is in a need for this as well:

**Step 1**
Create `/templates/` folder inside your plugin, and create `custom.php` file inside of it, with temporary content for testing purposes such as

```
<?php 
echo "Hi";
```

**Step 2**
Add this code to your plugin:

```
add_filter( 'generate_rewrite_rules', function ( $wp_rewrite ){
    $wp_rewrite->rules = array_merge(
        ['mypage/?$' => 'index.php?custom=1'],
        $wp_rewrite->rules
    );
} );
add_filter( 'query_vars', function( $query_vars ){
    $query_vars[] = 'custom';
    return $query_vars;
} );
add_action( 'template_redirect', function(){
    $custom = intval( get_query_var( 'custom' ) );
    if ( $custom ) {
        include plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'templates/custom.php';
        die;
    }
} );
```

**Please note** that `plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ )` may not be appropriate function for your case, depending on where you will add this code.

**Step 3**
Go to WP admin -> Settings -> Permalinks and re-save them, to flush/recreate permalinks.

**Step 4**
Try to visit `yoursite.com/mypage`. 
Clear your browser cache / history, or maybe even try incognito/different browser.

**Step 5**
Remove the testing code from `custom.php` file and add your own backend code.

Comment: This works 100%. Thanks for posting.